# NavigationBar item drops me to whichever navigation action I chose the first time

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am creating an app with 4 fragments (Home, Webshop, Cart, Profile). I have one activity (MainActivity) and a NavigationBar. When I'm on the Home page, I don't use the NavigationBar so it's hidden, I use the icons on the page instead for navigation (with Navigation Graph actions) and for this I use the icons' onClickListeners.
So if I click on for example the Webshop, it nicely takes me to the Webshop fragment, from here I can navigate to the Cart and the Profile fragments.
But not to the Home one...
Whenever I click on the Home icon on the NavigationBar, it takes me to the Webshop (the fragment I chose the first time I navigated from the Home page). Same thing happens if I choose any other fragments the first time: if I choose the Cart first, then form then on whenever I click on the Home icon, it takes me to the Cart, and so on.
I have no idea what could be the problem. It seems like its permanently setting that if I navigate to the Home page, the setOnClickListener - that I used for the first time - is firing.

Here I first choose the Webshop, then it always takes me to the Webshop:
[image]

Here I first choose the Cart, then it always takes me to the Cart:
[image]

Here I first choose the Profile, then it always takes me to the Profile:
[image]

I have a feeling I can't use NavigationGraph and NavigationBar together, I tried to merge them together somehow but could not figure it out.

Here's some code:

**HomePageFragment**
[image]

**WebshopFragment**
[image]

**CartFragment**
[image]

**ProfileFragment**
[image]

**MainActivity**
[image]

**Bottom Navigation Menu XML**
[image]

**NavigationGraph**
[image]

Comment: Please provide some relevant code

Comment: Good idea, I did!

Answer (score 0):

On your `MainActivity` create global `navController` on top like you did for `appBarConfiguration`:

```
private lateinit var navController: NavController
```

Change `val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)` with `navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)`
Add below line like so:

```
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

And correct your function with this:

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

I could not write your code all over again because you've pasted in picture, if that does not work let me know.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that did not work, maybe the problem lies somewhere else, but I am trying to figure it out since then, I tried to simplify my question, could you please look at this one here too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647961/how-to-set-in-android-to-be-navigated-to-the-same-fragment-every-time-from-the-b
It's the same problem but I just tried to ask it in a more straightforward way here, because I feel like i overcomplicated this one.