# How to set in Android to be navigated to the same fragment every time from the bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview, fragment-backstack, android-bottomnav

I have 4 fragments: **A**, **B**, **C** and **X**.

**A**, **B** and **C** are found on the bottom navigation bar, so every time I click on item **A**, I get the **A** fragment on the screen, click on **B**, I get **B**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I click on **C**, I get the **C** fragment, which has a button, that takes me to **X** fragment.
Now my problem is, that if I click on the Navigate to **X** button, after that when I navigate to anywhere from there and then back again on **C**, I get **X**.

[image]

But everytime I click on the item **C**, I want to get back to fragment **C**, no matter if I got to the **X** fragment before that.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I needed to **pop** the **X** fragment off the stack, with adding this to the action tag navigating to it:

`app:popUpTo='nav_graph_id'`

and

`app:popUpToInclusive="true"`